# sprite and image optimization with asp.net mvc2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I would like to use sprite and image optimization framework with my asp.net mvc 2 application.
I sprit dll are perfectly working with asp.net mvc3 and 4 framework.
I have downloaded sprite dlls from
 http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/65787

but same sprite dlls are not working with asp.net mvc 2 application.

I think i need to change sprite framework to target mvc 2 application.

if any one already did this could you please guide me on this?

Thanks and Regards,
Prashant

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to upgrade your project to mvc4?

Comment: at this point its not possible to upgrade to mvc4. we have plan for next release or so... right now many of the users are facing slow performance of page so i check almost everything in code and in database side also everything is working with high performance so i decided to use sprite and image optimization framework for now in my project. ( also same my application page i build in asp.net mvc4 with sprite framework and it shows awesome performance.)

Comment: Don't know the answer to your question. But most of that performance is probably coming from the fact that it is caching the images at client side and you are not. It is possible to make sprites even without mvcs framework, Since you already built the page in mvc4 you could just pick up the image and css from there.

Comment: yes got your point.. i will try to use same css and images from mvc4 project. this will work for me. Thanks for your time and reply.